# How to pass values in anonymous block with plsql table parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

Table abc has the following column

```
 approved_ain
    1
    2
    12
    34
```

i have a procedure

```
create or replace procedure abc( p_admin varchar2,
p_approved_ain  abc.approved_ain)--plsql table in parameter

begin

end;
```

now when i call this procedure in an anonymous block :-

```
declare 
l_Admin varchar2(100);
l_approved_ain abc.approved_ain;

begin
abc(l_Admin ,l_approved_ain);
commit;

end;
```

How can i pass values of the approved_ain of plsql table to this anonymous block.? that is i want to test it by passing the values of abc table approved_ain column.......

Answer :

```
 declare 
    l_Admin varchar2(100);
    l_approved_ain abc.approved_ain;

    begin
l_approved_ain(1) :=123;
l_approved_ain(2) :=4645;
    abc(l_Admin ,l_approved_ain);
    commit;

    end;
```

Comment: You can't pass parameters to anonymous PL/SQL block. Instead the block have to read the values from somewhere.

Comment: the question is how to erad values from somewhere

Comment: You can't have both table `abc` and procedure `abc` in the same schema, their names conflict. `abc.approved_ain` is a column reference not a data type reference unless `abc` is also your schema name.  In which case how is `abc.approved_ain` defined?

Comment: If I execute `create table abc (approved_ain number);` then execute your create procedure statement I encounter `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object` changing the procedure name to abc_p yeields `PLS-00488: 'ABC.APPROVED_AIN' must be a type`

Comment: i have added the answer.. this worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that you only want to test, what about just setting the values in the anonymous block:

```
declare 
l_Admin varchar2(100) := 'string';
l_approved_ain abc.approved_ain := ???;

begin
abc(l_Admin ,l_approved_ain);
commit;

end;
```