# Pass a table name and time stamp variable to a PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, timestamp, dynamic-sql

I am writing a below PL/SQL code in SQL developer to delete data from a table with a timestamp column in the where condition. How can I modify this code to pass the table name and the timestamp value to values that I want based on what table and time records I want to delete the data from and create a stored procedure that can be reused.

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE;
    
DECLARE
    counter   INTEGER := 0;
    stop      INTEGER;
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('START');
    LOOP
        counter   := counter + 1;
        DELETE my_schema.test
        WHERE t = '10-JUN-20 04.33.46.000000000 AM'
              AND   ROWNUM <= 100000;

        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        INTO   stop
        FROM my_schema.test
        WHERE t = '10-JUN-20 04.33.46.000000000 AM';

        EXIT WHEN stop <= 0;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;

    dbms_output.put_line('Counter: ' || counter);
    dbms_output.put_line('Left: ' || stop);
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass values in anonymous block with plsql table parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31556530/how-to-pass-values-in-anonymous-block-with-plsql-table-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting your anonymous to a stored procedure will, as indicated, require converting it to dynamic SQL. Always more difficult. And subject to SQL injection. For this you should validate string replacement parameters. I have a couple other changes:

- Pass the desired as a timestamp, not a string, this allows/forces the
  calling routine to determine the format and necessary conversion, if
  any.
- Added a parameter for column name as well. This frees naming columns
  from the requirement of the procedure.
- There is no need to count remaining items. Your loop processes until
  that value reaches 0, but this can be determined by the number of
  rows deleted on the last pass. Delete sets sql%rowcount to the number
  of rows deleted. When the pass deletes 0 rows the process is
  complete.
- Removed the results display and the commit from the procedure, again
  offloading this to the caller.

```
create or replace
procedure delete_values_by_timestamp
          ( p_table_name   in varchar2
          , p_column_name  in varchar2
          , p_timestamp    in timestamp
          , p_result_msg  out varchar2
          )

IS
    table_name_parameter_invalid  exception;
    pragma exception_init(table_name_parameter_invalid,  -44002);
    column_name_parameter_invalid exception;
    pragma exception_init(column_name_parameter_invalid, -44003);    

    k_nl                        constant varchar2(1) := chr(10);
    k_max_delete_per_interation constant integer     := 100000;
    k_base_delete varchar2(256) :=
                 'delete from <table_name>'     ||
                  ' where <column_name> <= :1'  ||
                  '  and rownum <= :2';

    v_delete_sql    varchar2 (256) ;
    v_rows_deleted  integer  := 0;

begin 
    v_delete_sql := replace(replace(k_base_delete,'<table_name>', dbms_assert.sql_object_name(p_table_name))
                         ,'<column_name>',dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(p_column_name));

    dbms_output.put_line('Running SQL:' || k_nl || v_delete_sql);
    loop
       execute immediate v_delete_sql using p_timestamp, k_max_delete_per_interation;
       exit when sql%rowcount = 0;
       v_rows_deleted :=v_rows_deleted + sql%rowcount;       
    end loop;

    if v_rows_deleted = 0
    then
        p_result_msg := 'No Data Found';
    else
        p_result_msg := 'Number of Rows Deleted ' || to_char(v_rows_deleted);
    end if;
exception
    when table_name_parameter_invalid then
         raise_application_error(-20199,'Invalid Table Name (' || p_table_name || ') specified.');
    when column_name_parameter_invalid then
         raise_application_error(-20198,'Invalid Column Name (' || p_column_name || ') specified.');        
         
end delete_values_by_timestamp;
```

See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2b8b676521dde7561a608fd37e05d745): In the example I reduce the number of rows deleted on each iteration from 100000 to 20.  An additionally enhancement would be to pass the number of rows for each iteration as a parameter.

Comment: I get an error when I execute the procedure saying wrong type or number of arguments execute delete_values_by_timestamp ('DETAIL_TABLE', 'TIME','11-JUN-19 09.22.54.000000000 AM') ;  What can be a reason?

Comment: The procedure has an OUT parameter, in order to return message, which you have to suppl when calling the routine. If you do not want a message returned then delete the p_result_message from the parameter list and the settings in the procedure to dbms_output or delete them.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test it but you could create a function whcih takes the table name and the timestamp as parameter.
As long you want to delete every record with the given timestamp you don't need to loop for each record.
This function should be just an example.

```
FUNCTION delete_values_by_timestamp (p_table_name   IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                     p_timestamp    IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    v_count   NUMBER := 0;
    v_query   VARCHAR2 (500) := '';
BEGIN
    IF p_table_name IS NOT NULL
    THEN
        IF p_timestamp IS NOT NULL
        THEN
            v_query := 'SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM my_schema.' || p_table_name | '
                        WHERE t = TO_DATE(''' || p_timestamp ||''', ''DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSSS'')';

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query INTO   v_count;
            
            IF v_count > 0
            THEN
                v_query := 'DELETE FROM my_schema.' || p_table_name || '
                            WHERE t = TO_DATE(''' || p_timestamp ||''', ''DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSSS'')';

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query;
            ELSE
                RETURN 'NO RECORDS FOUND!';
            END IF;
        ELSE
            RETURN 'TIMESTAMP EMPTY!';
        END IF;
    ELSE
        RETURN 'TABLE NAME EMPTY!';
    END IF;
END;
```